# What is a job quote?

Tags: word-meaning

This is the headline of an [online article](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/prepare-quote-job-11305.html)

> How to Prepare a Quote for a Job

The closest meaning I've found in dictionaries is an *estimate*, but what does a job estimate mean? Is it all about telling the employer my *rate*?

Comment: A "job" can also mean a "project". The quote states the price you are going to charge for the completed work product and the scope of the work and it can include ancillary details like a promised delivery date and a payment schedule, if payment is not in one lump sum upon delivery but is broken out into a downpayment, another partial payment upon delivery, and then a final payment after a testing  period and final acceptance of the work.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: I believe that is an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @sharur: You're welcome to your beliefs. To me, it looks like a comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

If someone asks you to do a job, for example, they ask you to make a website, they will ask you how much you will charge before you begin work.

They will ask you to give them a "quote" or an "estimate". The difference is that an "estimate" may be changed later, if there are unexpected problems. A quote should be a fixed price (in practice this distinction may not be strictly observed).

A client will probably get several quotes and choose the cheapest that fulfils their requirements. If a client asks for a quote you should tell them how much you would charge to do the job.

This only applies to contract work, not salaries or wage-work.